# Anti forgery exceptions everyday on live system for failed login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, ip, antiforgerytoken

I get around 500+ anti forgery exceptions everyday on live system. I have blocked few IPs but every day it comes from different IPs. All of this is from the failed logins. Is there any solution to this kind of attack?

Comment: Are you sure they are actually attacks and not any load tests running on the application

Comment: I am sure they are not load testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Well Anti-Forgery-Token is there to prevent forgery, so it is doing it's job well by not allowing automated attacks. Blocking specific IP's might block legitimate users behind those IP's. 
Since you're saying that it's not any of your automated tests and it comes from different IPs everyday, and you're suspicious about intentional attacks then I would rather suggest you to stop worrying about Anti-Forgery Exceptions, and instead focus on preventing DDOS attacks. 500 requests/day is not much, but as a safeguard start focusing on Denial of Service.